# Find nested values in mongo 3 with java

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a document in my mongo collection that looks like this:

```
{ 
  "timestamp": 1460442540,
  "page": "home",
  "misc": {
             "color": "red",
             "light": "off" 
          }
}
```

What I want to be able to do is return the value of *misc.color* when a certain condition is met on *page*.

This is what I have:

```
   //find my query match
   Document value = mongoDBService.getCollection(collectionName)
            .find(eq("page", "home")).first();

    //prints json described above
    LOG.info(value.toString());

    //prints "misc" subdocument
    LOG.info(value.get("misc").toString());

    //null pointer
    LOG.info(value.get("misc.color").toString());
```

Is there some way to handle the dot notation here that I am missing? Ideally I want this query to be dynamic so it can handle dot notation values and higher level values.

I am using mongodb-driver 3.4.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can update your code to below.

```
Document value = mongoDBService.getCollection(collectionName)
            .find(eq("page", "home")).first();

LOG.info(value.get("misc", Document.class).getString("color"));
```

Comment: where is **eq** method?

Comment: sorry buddy. got it. Its in **Filters** class. but it took me a another google search. if you specified, it is more help

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
BasicDBObject query = (BasicDBObject)(value.get("misc")).getString("color");
```